# Google Check-out and promotions

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce, google-checkout

I've started working on some enhancements to an ASP.NET web forms e-commerce project, one of the tasks is to add promotion codes to the check-out page.

Currently, the site is using Google Checkout (via the GCheckoutButton that comes with the .NET sample pack), the trouble is I can't find any sensible way to add the promotion to the Google Check-out XML request...

Has anyone done this before, or should I just apply the discounts to the items before putting them into Google?

Thanks,
Kieron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect, but adding the last shopping cart item with a minus value, and a sensible description did the trick.